# C++ in-place class instantiation

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, instantiation

Take a lot at this (working) code

```
class MyClass {
public:
  double data[6];
  double func() const {
      return data[1] + 2*data[3];
  }
};

double takeMyClassReference(const MyClass &obj) {
    return obj.func();
}

void construct(const double y[]) {
    const MyClass *obj = reinterpret_cast<const MyClass *>(y);
    double val = takeMyClassReference(*obj);
    // do something with val
}
```

this code does what I want and it is efficient, the start of construct was translated to

```
movsd   24(%rdi), %xmm0
addsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
addsd   8(%rdi), %xmm0
```

which is as efficient as it gets.

Is it possible to write this in a safer way, without a reinterpret_cast, but without sacrificing speed? I cannot change the signature of `construct` or `takeMyClassReference`.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why a double not `std::uintptr_t`? It wouldn't change your function body, but the array type would make more sense.

Comment: Because a double precision floating point number is not a pointer?

Comment: Why don't you make `MyClass` take a `double *data` argument for the constructor instead of the member array?

Comment: I want the MyClass object to own the data, because at different places in the code, I copy a MyClass object and I want it to deep-copy the array.

Comment: Neither is `std::uintptr_t`. My question still stands.

Comment: Because I want to do floating point arithmetic on the 6 elements of y?

Comment: What is the aim? In `construct` you could do `double val = y[0] + 2*y[3];`, why do you need `MyClass` ?

Comment: For readability. double val = y[0] + 2*y[3]; has zero type-safety and if you have lots of these, something will go wrong

Comment: Sense or non-sense, the question is not uninteresting in general. Imagine a `struct Matrix4x4 { double value[16]; };` and another `struct Vector4 { double[4]; };`. I _really_ would enjoy a function `const Vector4& getRow(const Matrix4x4 &mat, unsigned i) { return *(const Vector4*)(mat.values + i * 4); }`. (I assume this is a similar use case like the one of OP but I might have misunderstood OPs issue.)

Comment: @sweenish 'Clever'? First adjective that came to my mind was 'reckless' :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to move from MyClass owning the data, to MyClass not owning the data.

```
class MyClass {
public:
  double *data;
  double func() const {
      return data[1] + 2*data[3];
  }
};
void construct(double y[]) {
    MyClass obj;
    obj.data = y;
    double val = takeMyClassReference(obj);
    // do something with val
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only allowed way of doing this is with `std::memcpy`:

```
void construct(const double y[]) {
    MyClass x;
    std::memcpy(&x,y,sizeof x);
    double val = takeMyClassReference(x);
    // do something with val
}
```

Clang [already optimizes this perfectly](https://www.godbolt.org/z/resdEahb4); ICC comes close (but misses the strength reduction of using addition), while GCC generates useless stack stores (including one *after* the math, oddly).